# Iterating through two list and pulling data out of both depending on circumstances from the first list

Tags: python-2.7, loops

I have two list and I'm trying to form a single list based on circumstances of the first list.

Here's my code.

the first list:

```
ac = [1,3,5,-2,7,10,13,40,-8,-9,-5,-3]
```

the second list:

```
bd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

the code I'm trying to use.

```
grt = []
for r in range(0, len(ac)):
   for t in range(0, len(bd)):    
       if ac[r] > 3:
           ac[r] = bd[t]
       elif ac[r] <-3:
           ac[r] = bd[t]
       else:
           ac[r] = 0
       grt.append(ac[r])
print grt
```

This doesn't work...

I'm trying to get this:

```
[0,0,3,0,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,0]
```

Thanks for your help. If you need me to change anything or explain anything in more detail or anything, please comment and I will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension and `zip`:

```
>>> bd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> ac = [1,3,5,-2,7,10,13,40,-8,-9,-5,-3]
>>>
>>> [0 if a in range(-3, 4) else b for a, b in zip(ac, bd)]
[0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0]
```

`zip` generates pairs of items from `ac` and `bd`, then `if a in range(-3,4) else b` (a [ternary operator](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html)) puts the right item in the comprehension depending on the evaluation of the condition.

```
grt = [0 if a in range(-3, 4) else b for a, b in zip(ac, bd)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if the list are composed of floats would i have to change them just curious?

Comment: It doesn't work with floats it automatically copies from bd.

Comment: You should modify the `ternary operator`: `[0 if a > -3 and a < 4 else b for a, b in zip(ac, bd)]` as floats will not be found in `range(...)`

Comment: thanks man i really appreciate it. It's a learning process for me i'm still pretty new at.

Answer (score 1):

There's seems to be a very simply error in your code when you are trying to set the list at certain indices equal to each other. You should write:

```
ac[r] = bd[t]
```

instead of

```
ac[r] == bd[t]
```

The line you have written (with two "=") is comparing ac[r] to bd[t], while you actually want to set those two values equal, using only one "=". You would use two equals signs within a boolean (true/false) expression, but not to set variables equal to each other. To fix your code, simply use one equals sign instead of two when you are setting lists at certain indices equal to each other.